# Second monitor not detected Nvidia ubuntu 14.04

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors

I'm relatively new to ubuntu. I have an HP with intel xeon and Nvidia Quadro FX380 GPU with dual monitors( Dell 19" and HP 24". I've been happily using it for the past 6 months but last week I upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04, when I rebooted it, the second monitor disappeared.

First off I go the display settings to realize that the detect button doesn't detect my second display.

I've tried to upgrade Nvidia proprietary driver but the software manager shows me (Since I can't post images...) :

NVIDIA Corporation: G96GL [Quadro FX 380 ]

This device is using the recommended driver

-Using NVIDIA binary driver - version 331.38 from nvidia-331 (proprietary, tested)

And finally when I access X server display configuration in nvidia settings. It tells me that their is just one display.

I tried to reinstall the driver for the GPU and it crashed, I had to reinstall ubuntu.

Please help, I'm desperate to get my second display back.

Comment: So even after a clean wipe and reload and Using NVIDIA binary driver - version 331.38 from nvidia-331 (proprietary, tested) still didn't work?